# GroupBy on Records considering the highest value on a different column

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to process a set of records by grouping on two specific columns and taking the highest sequence number .

I have a table structure as follows:
**ProductDetails**

```
ID        CountryID          StateID       Sequence     IsProductMissing          IsProductLogicProcessed
1           1                  1                1            0                       0
2           1                  1                2            1                       0
3           1                  1                3            0                       0

4           2                  2                1            0                       0
5           2                  2                2            1                       0

6           4                  6                1            1                       0
```

My expected output would be :

```
ID        CountryID          StateID       Sequence     IsProductMissing          IsProductLogicProcessed
5           2                  2                2            1                       0
6           4                  6                1            1                       0
```

I have to filter the records where **IsProductMissing** is **true** and **IsProductLogicProcessed** is **false** for the combination of **CountryID** and **StateID** on the highest SequenceNumber record only.

Since the **IsProductMissing** is **true** and **IsProductLogicProcessed** is **false** on the highest Sequence Number for the combination of **CountryID** and **StateID**,IDs 5 and 6 are filtered.

--

I have tried following things.

```
var takeDistinctCountryIDStateID = (await _ProductDetails.GetAll().Where(x=>x.IsProductMissing == true &&
x.IsProductLogicProcessed == false).Select(x=>new {
x.CountryID,
x.StateID
}).Distinct().Take(20)).ToListAsync());
```

```
var joinOnACtualTable = await(from p _ProductDetails.GetAll()
                             join s in takeDistinctCountryIDStateID 
                             on new {p.CountryID,p.StateID} equals new {s.CountryID,s.StateID}
                             select p).ToListAsync();
```

```
var actualOutput = from t in joinOnACtualTable 
                   group t by new { a = t.CountryID,b=t.StateID} into g
                   select g.OrderByDescending(b=>b.Sequence).FirstOrDefault();
```

There are two problems in the other queries

1. Incorrect set of Records : I would get output wrongly as

```
     ID        CountryID          StateID       Sequence     IsProductMissing          IsProductLogicProcessed
        3           1                  1                3            0                       0
        5           2                  2                2            1                       0
        6           4                  6                1            1                       0
```

Since for the Combination of **(CountryID,StateID) (1,1)** the second sequence has 
IsProductMissing = 1,
IsProductLogicProcessed = 0 it has incorrectly picked ID Number 3 as well.

2. In the linq query number 2 , the output window shows it is doing join by bringing all the records from ProductDetails table in memory which is very inefficient .

If I have 1 million records it would time out eventually.

So, how to simplify this and get the expected output using Linq/lambda expressions?

Comment: Could you please give us your sample data via https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

//for your candidate element with x.IsProductMissing == true &&
                        x.IsProductLogicProcessed == false
//check if this is the highest sequence for StateId and CountryId by seeing if any higher sequence exists for that StateId and countryId

```
            var yourList = (await _ProductDetails.GetAll());

            var takeDistinctCountryIDStateID = (yourList.Where(x => x.IsProductMissing == true &&
                    x.IsProductLogicProcessed == false && !yourList.Where(y=> y.StateId == x.StateId && y.CountryID == x.CountryID && y.Sequece > x.Sequence).Any()).Select(x => new {
                    x.CountryID,
                    x.StateID
                    }).Distinct().Take(20)).ToListAsync());
```

this will maybe be poor-performance for 1 million records - you might want to use a sorted list and use binarySearching techniques via Lambda functions to speed it up